# Broadcasting a function over two vectors to get a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, array-broadcasting

I want to broadcast a function f over a vectors so that the result is a matrix P where P[i,j] = f(v[i], v[j]).
I know that I can do it simply:

```
P = zeros( (v.shape[0], v.shape[0]) )
for i in range(P.shape[0]):
    for j in range(P.shape[0]):
        P[i, j] = f(v[i,:], v[j,:])
```

or more hacky:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
P = cdist(v, v, metric=f)
```

But I am looking for the fastest and neatest way to do it.
This seems like a function of broadcasting that numpy should have built-in.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If it works, `cdist` looks like a pretty clean way of doing this.  In the case of a callable `metric`, `cdist` does exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: So `f(a,b)` takes 2 1d arrays, and returns a scalar?

Comment: `f1 = functools.partial(cdist, metric=f)` would hide the `cdist` usage.

Comment: @Gioelelm I am almost sure you can avoid the loops perhaps redesigning a bit your code... where do you use `P[i, j]`... do you need all the distance matrix or only to find the closest points for some reason... in that case, check `scipy.spatial.distance.cKDTree()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you search for is [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). Use it like so:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x + y
v = numpy.array([1,2,3])
# vectorize the function
vf = numpy.vectorize(f)
# "transposing" the vector by producing a view with another shape
vt = v.reshape((v.shape[0], 1)
# calculate over all combinations using broadcast
vf(v, vt)

Output:
array([[ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

Comment: `vectorize` doesn't speed it up.  It just wraps the loop(s), while giving access to broadcasting machinery.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but believe thats exactly what he wants. Speedy numpy-level loops while being memory efficient via broadcasting.

Comment: But I don't see where broadcasting is used in his sample code.

Comment: @itai Yes that is what I wanted, this is for sure faster than my loop

Comment: @hpaulj you probably got it yourself but for posterity - v is broadcasted "vertically" (shape (3,1) to (3,3)) and vt is broadcasted "horizontally" (shape (1,3) to (3,3)).