# Mathematica like outer product in Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica allows a general two argument function to be applied to outer product. For example

Outer[f,{a,b},{x,y}] produces {{f[a,x],f[a,y]},{f[b,x],f[b,y]}}

In Python the function f is fixed as multiplication in outer. So for example

outer({a,b},{x,y}) in Python is the same as Outer[Times,{a,b},{x,y}] in Mathematica.

If there a way I can apply a general function like f in the Python version of outer?

I have considered just using something other then outer or using a for loop, but it would be nice to know I could mirror Mathematica.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923397/broadcasting-a-function-over-two-vectors-to-get-a-2d-numpy-array The questioner's desired *"result is a matrix P where P[i,j] = f(v[i], v[j])"* - which sounds like your desired generalised outer product.

Comment: If you want to mirror it, you can look in the: [Mathics - Outer class](https://github.com/Mathics3/mathics-core/blob/b6ba601b0b21a345bee30abfebb360d1409ef7de/mathics/builtin/tensors.py#L274)